AWS WAF Trusted IP List
I have a AWS WAF with some managed ruleset.
What I wanted to achieve is follow: 
If IP Address in the whitelist, ignore all the rules configured in the WAF and allow everything. 
Else, proceed to check the WAF rules and BLOCK accordingly.
Some sort of trusted IP where AWS WAF will ignore all the ruleset.
I am unable to find these feature. Hope someone can shed some light.

Ideas here.
